# Correct way to use reified generic in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

I want to rewrite little extension function for `SharedPreferences`. Right now it looks like this

```
fun SharedPreferences.put(arg: Pair<String, Any>) {
    val e = edit()
    val s = arg.second
    when (s) {
        is Int -> e.putInt(arg.first, s)
        is String -> e.putString(arg.first, s)
        is Boolean -> e.putBoolean(arg.first, s)
        is Long -> e.putLong(arg.first, s)
        else -> throw NotImplementedError("Extension not implemented for this type")
    }
    e.apply()
}
```

Is there are any idiomatic way to use generic with `when`?

My first guess is

```
inline fun <reified T> SharedPreferences.put(arg: Pair<String, T>) {
    val e = edit()
    when (T::class) {
        Int::class -> e.putInt(arg.first, arg.second as Int)
        String::class -> e.putString(arg.first, arg.second as String)
        Boolean::class -> e.putBoolean(arg.first, arg.second as Boolean)
        Long::class -> e.putLong(arg.first, arg.second as Long)
        else -> throw NotImplementedError("Extension not implemented for this type")
    }
    e.apply()
}
```

But it's looking a bit creepy and not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid the `when`-statement, you can create overloads for each type:

```
inline fun SharedPreferences.put(arg: Pair<String, Int>) {
    edit().putInt(arg.first, arg.second).apply()
}

inline fun SharedPreferences.put(arg: Pair<String, String>) {
    edit().putString(arg.first, arg.second).apply()
}

inline fun SharedPreferences.put(arg: Pair<String, Boolean>) {
    edit().putBoolean(arg.first, arg.second).apply()
}

inline fun SharedPreferences.put(arg: Pair<String, Long>) {
    edit().putLong(arg.first, arg.second).apply()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for correct answer, but I'm trying to learn generics) That's why question title is `Correct way to use reified generic`

Comment: @DimaRostopira Please accept the answer if this was what you were looking for :)

Comment: I'm waiting for solution with generics, will accept tomorrow if there are won't be better answer

Comment: Holy... I of course also want to write like this, but it won't compile! The JVM erasure is the same! (`(Landroid/content/SharedPreferences, Lkotlin/Pair)V`) If you really want to use overload, you should use `fun SharedPreferences.put(key: String, val: XXX)`.

Comment: @glee8e add `@JvmName("putXXX")` for each func, not a big deal. `fun SharedPreferences.put(key: String, val: XXX)` looks then like `put("key", value)` but I prefer `put("key" to value)` and even better `defaultSharedPreferences.set("key" to true)`

Comment: Ah, I forgot about those `JvmName`s. My fault.

Answer (score 2):

Your first version is the correct and idiomatic way. Kotlin has smart cast, so you have `is Int -> e.putInt(arg.first, s)` instead of `is Int -> e.putInt(arg.first, s as Int)`. That is all kotlin can do for you.

Comment: My goal is that compiled code will look as one line instead of switch

Answer (score 0):

**This the way to implement generic shared preference functions.**
Use these two functions I mentioned in bellowed in your util class (whatever class that isolated from your activity or fragment)

```
    inline fun <reified T> SharedPreferences.get(key: String, defaultValue: T): T {
    when (T::class) {
        Boolean::class -> return this.getBoolean(key, defaultValue as Boolean) as T
        Float::class -> return this.getFloat(key, defaultValue as Float) as T
        Int::class -> return this.getInt(key, defaultValue as Int) as T
        Long::class -> return this.getLong(key, defaultValue as Long) as T
        String::class -> return this.getString(key, defaultValue as String) as T
        else -> {
            if (defaultValue is Set<*>) {
                return this.getStringSet(key, defaultValue as Set<String>) as T
            }
        }
    }

    return defaultValue
}

inline fun <reified T> SharedPreferences.put(key: String, value: T) {
    val editor = this.edit()

    when (T::class) {
        Boolean::class -> editor.putBoolean(key, value as Boolean)
        Float::class -> editor.putFloat(key, value as Float)
        Int::class -> editor.putInt(key, value as Int)
        Long::class -> editor.putLong(key, value as Long)
        String::class -> editor.putString(key, value as String)
        else -> {
            if (value is Set<*>) {
                editor.putStringSet(key, value as Set<String>)
            }
        }
    }

    editor.apply()
}
```

Now you can use these two functions in your activity/fragment

**Activity**

```
val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(prefKey, Context.MODE_PRIVATE) 
sharedPreferences.put(key, valueYouWantoStore) //value can be any type mentioned in put function
val value = sharedPreferences.get(Enums.signInState, defaultvalue)
```

**Fragment**

```
val sharedPreferences = this.requireActivity().getSharedPreferences(prefKey, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
sharedPreferences.put(key, valueYouWantoStore) //value can be any type mentioned in put function
val value = sharedPreferences.get(Enums.signInState, defaultvalue)
```